# EC2 yum update fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, updates, yum

I have an instance on EC2 running Amazon's AMI.  Beginning this week, I'm unable to complete a   yum update due to an issue with dependency resolution:

```
$  yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.3 kB     00:00
652 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package device-mapper-event.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-event.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.i686 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.i686 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package device-mapper-libs.i686 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-libs.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-libs.i686 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package device-mapper-libs.x86_64 0:1.02.77-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libblkid.i686 0:2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libblkid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686
---> Package libblkid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libblkid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686
---> Package libblkid.i686 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libblkid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libuuid.i686 0:2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libuuid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686
---> Package libuuid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libuuid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686
---> Package libuuid.i686 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libuuid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 0:2.02.98-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 0:2.02.98-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package lvm2-libs.x86_64 0:2.02.98-9.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package lvm2-libs.x86_64 0:2.02.98-9.20.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package util-linux-ng.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package util-linux-ng.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libblkid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1
           Removing: libblkid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-main)
               libblkid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1
           Updated By: libblkid-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.i686 (amzn-updates)
               libblkid = 2.17.2-13.17.amzn1
Error: Package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libuuid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1
           Removing: libuuid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-main)
               libuuid = 2.17.2-13.16.amzn1
           Updated By: libuuid-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.i686 (amzn-updates)
               libuuid = 2.17.2-13.17.amzn1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I really don't think removing `util-linux-ng` to resolve the dependency would be a good solution as I'm seeing quite a few critical tools in that package.  Does anyone have a good solution?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to wait for Amazon to update to *util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.i686*

In the meantime, you can follow the suggestion:

```
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

By running:

```
yum update --skip-broken
```

To update everything else.

Comment: I already tried that.  It allowed all other packages to get updated, but util-linux-ng still remains.

Comment: That's what `--skip-broken` is supposed to do. You'll still have to wait for Amazon to update `util-linux-ng` in their repository.

Answer (score 3):

```
yum clean all
```

and

```
yum update
```

fixed the issue for me.

`yum clean all` will remove everything that yum caches, ensure you are not relying on any cached data before running the command.